# SQL Server : where with same date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using SQL Server. I have two date filters using those fields as show below in query.

```
SELECT * 
FROM student
WHERE 
    Dateofbirth >= '2014-10-03'
    AND Dateofbirth <= '2014-10-03'
```

While using this same date no result get listed. If I change the date to

```
SELECT * 
FROM student
WHERE 
    Dateofbirth >= '2014-10-03'
    AND Dateofbirth <= '2014-10-04'
```

I have my records listed.

This same query works fine in MySql. Can someone help me? Why is this not working in SQL Server?

Comment: What  is the type of the column `Dateofbirth`?

Comment: Check the date format of dateofbirth in table and given string

Comment: @SravaniAnnepu dates have no format, they are binary types.

Comment: Are you using a `date` or a `datetime` type? With a `date` type the original query would work. `datetime` includes a time component which means that `2014-10-03` corresponds to `2014-10-03 00:00`. If you don't want to store times, change your column's type to `date`

Comment: Also what are the *real* values stored in the column? If the birthdates had no time component, the query would work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the issue Dateofbirth  is probably a datetime column.

A datetime column has both a date part and time part.So, your query with date alone will translate as

```
SELECT * FROM student
WHERE Dateofbirth >= '2014-10-03 00:00:00.000'
AND Dateofbirth <= '2014-10-03 00:00:00.000'
```

So, to get the entire day the query should be like

```
SELECT * FROM student
WHERE Dateofbirth >= '2014-10-03 00:00:00.000'
AND Dateofbirth <= '2014-10-03 23:59:59.997
```

Comment: I would usually recommend switching to an *exclusive* endpoint - `< '2014-10-04'` is an easier endpoint to compute and think about, and you don't have to re-think the endpoint if you switch to `datetime2`s which can have more precision.

Comment: Also, the query would work if `DateOfBirth` contained only the date part. While this change will return results, it doesn't solve the real problem - dirty dates

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM student
WHERE Dateofbirth >= '2014-10-03'
AND Dateofbirth <= '2014-10-03'
```

This means show only data which have only  `2014-10-03` value. There is hour is also in your date, and your date string is without hour,minute, second. So in compare it will not get.

The problem will solved by type casting or proper format need when you working with date compare.

```
SELECT * FROM student
WHERE cast ( Dateofbirth as date) >= cast ( '2014-10-03' as date)
AND cast( Dateofbirth as date) <= cast( '2014-10-03' as date)
```

This will set both value in date portion not time.

When you use `2014-10-04` mean all hours including and get the result.

OR

you can user between operator also, which include the starting date and ending date.

```
SELECT * FROM student
WHERE cast ( Dateofbirth as date) between cast ( '2014-10-03' as date) and cast ( '2014-10-04' as date)

or 
SELECT * FROM student
WHERE Dateofbirth  between '2014-10-03' and '2014-10-04'
```

Comment: There's no reason to cast the filter values to `date`

Answer (score 1):

The query should work if you stored only dates in `Dateofbirth`. If you try the following script you'll get the expected results, `AAA`, `BBB`:

```
create table students(
    ID int primary key identity,
    Name varchar(50),
    Dateofbirth datetime)


insert into students (Name,Dateofbirth)
values ('AAA','2014-10-03'),
    ('BBB','2014-10-03'),
    ('CCC','2014-10-04')



select * 
from students 
where Dateofbirth between '2014-10-03' and '2014-10-03'

select * 
from students 
where Dateofbirth>='2014-10-03' and Dateofbirth<='2014-10-03'
```

I suspect you store birth dates using a `datetime` column. `datetime` includes time which means that a `2014-10-03` actually is `2014-10-03 00:00:00`. I suspect that either a bug or an ETL quirk adds a time component, perhaps in the form of a time zone offset?

You should change the column's type to `date`, which stores only dates. This makes business sense as I doubt that you want to store the actual birth time of students, and prevents accidental time entries.

If you don't want to change the column's type, you can cast the field's value to `date` before comparing. Normally, applying any kind of operation on a field value means you can't use any underlying indexes. In this case SQL Server is smart enough to detect the cast and use any underlying indexes on the `Dateofbirth` column:

```
select *
from students 
where cast(BirthDate as date)>='2014-10-04' and cast(BirthDate as date)<='2014-10-04'
```

You'd still have to clean up the dirty Dates of Birth though, to remove any unwanted time components.

Answer (score -1):

As already mentioned, the time-part of your column (hour/minute etc) is the reason for that behavior.

In T-SQL, you can also use [DATEDIFF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms189794.aspx) to get the data for one specific date:

```
SELECT * FROM student
WHERE DATEDIFF(d, Dateofbirth, '2014-10-03') = 0
```

Comment: Applying a function to a column means you can't use any indexes and should be avoided at all costs. This forces a full table scan, resulting in unacceptable performance. That's why a `date` type or comparison to next date are used in such scenarios